# php how to check database and set a var based on db value

Tags: php, sql, database

Okay I asked this once but I am terrible at wording and asking the right questions so here we go again. Sorry if it's hard to understand and any help I really do appreciate. I work fulltime as a driver and this is a side project I'm doing so I don't have the most time needed and these roadblocks tend to become really time consuming at times.

This is the code I have at the moment.

```
<td><b>LVL:</b> <?php echo $_SESSION['userlvl']; ?></td>
```

this is my php code

```
$query = ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userexp='$userexp'");

$userexp = 0;
$userlvl = 1;
$_SESSION['userlvl'] = $userlvl;
$_SESSION['userexp'] = $userexp;

if ($userexp >= 27586350412){$userlvl = 50;}
else if ($userexp >= 22069080330){$userlvl = 50;}
else if ($userexp >= 20434333639){$userlvl = 49;}
else if ($userexp >= 18920679295){$userlvl = 48;}
else if ($userexp >= 17519147496){$userlvl = 47;}
else if ($userexp >= 16221432867){$userlvl = 46;}
else if ($userexp >= 10814288578){$userlvl = 45;}
else if ($userexp >= 10013230164){$userlvl = 44;}
else if ($userexp >= 9271509412){$userlvl = 43;}
else if ($userexp >= 8428644920){$userlvl = 42;}
else if ($userexp >= 7662404473){$userlvl = 41;}
else if ($userexp >= 6965822249){$userlvl = 40;}
else if ($userexp >= 6332565681){$userlvl = 39;}
else if ($userexp >= 5756877892){$userlvl = 38;}
else if ($userexp >= 4605502313){$userlvl = 37;}
else if ($userexp >= 3684401851){$userlvl = 36;}
else if ($userexp >= 2456267901){$userlvl = 35;}
else if ($userexp >= 1965014321){$userlvl = 34;}
else if ($userexp >= 1572011457){$userlvl = 33;}
else if ($userexp >= 1257609166){$userlvl = 32;}
else if ($userexp >= 1006087333){$userlvl = 31;}
else if ($userexp >= 574907047){$userlvl = 30;}
else if ($userexp >= 328518313){$userlvl = 29;}
else if ($userexp >= 187724750){$userlvl = 28;}
else if ($userexp >= 107271286){$userlvl = 27;}
else if ($userexp >= 56458571){$userlvl = 26;}
else if ($userexp >= 28229285){$userlvl = 25;}
else if ($userexp >= 16131020){$userlvl = 24;}
else if ($userexp >= 9217726){$userlvl = 23;}
else if ($userexp >= 5267273){$userlvl = 22;}
else if ($userexp >= 3009870){$userlvl = 21;}
else if ($userexp >= 1719927){$userlvl = 20;}
else if ($userexp >= 955515){$userlvl = 19;}
else if ($userexp >= 530841){$userlvl = 18;}
else if ($userexp >= 294912){$userlvl = 17;}
else if ($userexp >= 163840){$userlvl = 16;}
else if ($userexp >= 81920){$userlvl = 15;}
else if ($userexp >= 40960){$userlvl = 14;}
else if ($userexp >= 20480){$userlvl = 13;}
else if ($userexp >= 10240){$userlvl = 12;}
else if ($userexp >= 5120){$userlvl = 11;}
else if ($userexp >= 2560){$userlvl = 10;}
else if ($userexp >= 1280){$userlvl = 9;}
else if ($userexp >= 640){$userlvl = 8;}
else if ($userexp >= 320){$userlvl = 7;}
else if ($userexp >= 160){$userlvl = 6;}
else if ($userexp >= 80){$userlvl = 5;}
else if ($userexp >= 40){$userlvl = 4;}
else if ($userexp >= 20){$userlvl = 3;}
else if ($userexp >= 10){$userlvl = 2;}
else if ($userexp >= 5){$userlvl = 1;}
```

now after all that the level sets a 1 even if I change the DB userexp to 5000. I wouldnt be surprised if it's any easy fix looking right at my face but I don't see it.

Comment: You're never executing the query or fetching the results. You need to read a tutorial on how to query a database from PHP. Also, you need to set the session variables AFTER all the `if` blockss.

Answer (score 0):

$conn = mysqli_connect("Your DB connect here");

session_start();

$userlvl = $_SESSION['userlvl'];

$userexp = $_SESSION['userexp'];

$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];

if ($userexp >= 27586350412){mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE users set userlevel = 50 where userid = $_SESSION[userid]");};

or

```
switch($userexp):

case($userexp >= 5):

mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE users set userlevel = 1 where userid = $_SESSION[userid]");

break;

case($userexp >= 10):

mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE users set userlevel = 2 where userid = $_SESSION[userid]");

break;

case($userexp >= 20):

mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE users set userlevel = 3 where userid = $_SESSION[userid]");

break;

case($userexp >= 40):

mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE users set userlevel = 4 where userid = $_SESSION[userid]");

break;

case($userexp >= 80):

mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE users set userlevel = 5 where userid = $_SESSION[userid]");

break;

default;

mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE users set userlevel = 0 where userid = $_SESSION[userid]"); 

endswitch;
```

I hope that's what you wanted.

Comment: Can you show me how youd use switch instead?

Comment: Yes it did help. Now I'm having a issue I have the code all running and it seems like I'm connected to my db because my login and register works but for some reason its not pulling the value from my db its just showing the information as blank.

Comment: You need another query in php to pull data from the database on your site.